# Always open camera in landscape mode in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app, after clicking on button I want camera to open in landscape mode. Even if I rotate my mobile into portrait mode, camera should always be in landscape mode or in portrait mode

Answer (score 5):

Use This code for open camera in landscape mode

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, Utils.CAMERA__CROP_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score -1):

Fix the orientation of that activity to landscape in your manifest. 
Like this

```
<activity
   android:name="YourActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

1. Add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the activity in your manifest.xml
2. Call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in your Activity'y `onCreate()` method.