# How to make custom camera which Capture horizontally always in Native Android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to capture a video always horizontally.

If the user rotates the phone, I want to capture the video horizontally.

I have one [reference](http://%20https://github.com/HorizonCamera/HorizonSDK-Android/) for that but I want to make it for my own with customization.

how can I implement this in a smooth way?

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879713/always-open-camera-in-landscape-mode-in-android

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks for your answer but I don't want horizontal orientation for mobile but I want to capture horizontally I don't want to block user to change their orientation. Just have a look at reference link you'll get more idea about that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(int phoneRotation, int cameraId, Camera camera) {
   Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    info = Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (phoneRotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360; 
    } else { 
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

when phoneRotation is
`int phoneRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();`

By the way this answer originally refactored from some answer in stackoverflow.